# Saving json dictionaries to a python dictionary with a loop, 'no JSON object' error

Tags: request

I'm compiling a lot of JSON data over API and getting an error: "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded" I have bolded the line that generates the error.

Most perplexing is that it successfully enters the first dictionary entry, but I get the error when it repeates the for loop.

The problematic cell of code looks like this. 'genkey' and 'conkey' are dictionaries with about 50 keys, each one has a five or six digit number as its value.

```
gdata={}
cdata={}
for site in genkeys:
    print genkeys[site]
    gpayload = {'data_key_id': gdatakey, 'range_start': rangestart, 'range_end': rangeend,'period':'hour', 'token':'5b'}
    gr = requests.get("http://appl.d.com/dta/raw.json?",params=gpayload)
    print gr
    print genkeys[site]
    **gdata[gdatakey]=gr.json()**
    if site in conkeys.keys():
        cdatakey=conkeys[site]
        cpayload = {'data_key_id': cdatakey, 'range_start': rangestart, 'range_end': rangeend,'period':'hour', 'token':'5b'}
        cr = requests.get("http://appl.d.com/dta/raw.json?",params=cpayload)
        cdata[cdatakey]=cr.json()
print gdata
print cdata
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a null entry in the json code. That's what threw the error.